# Error While Deploying AngularJS Project which communicates with a Spring RESTful web service returning JSON data

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, angularjs, rest

I am Creating AngularJS Project in Eclipse with The Following Project Structure :

[image: Project Screen Shot]

The **index.html** is as follows :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ToDoApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Script/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bootstrap.css" />
    <title>Question & Answer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The **app.js** is as follows :

```
var urlBase="http://LocalHost:8080/FetchQuestions/";
var ToDoApp = angular.module("ToDoApp", ['ngRoute','ngResource']).
config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
                    when('/service/question/', 
                    { controller: 'ListQuestionCtrl', 
                      templateUrl: urlBase+'ListQuestions.html'
                 }).when('/service/question/:tag1,:tag2,:tag3',
                    { controller: 'ListQuestionByTagsCtrl',
                      templateUrl: urlBase+'ListQuestions.html'
                 }).when('/service/question/insert/:user_id/:qtn_id/:answer',
                    { controller: 'InsertQuestionAnswerCtrl',
                      templateUrl: urlBase+'InsertAnswer.html'
                 }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});



ToDoApp.controller("ListQuestionCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('http://LocalHost:8080/FetchQuestions/service/question/').
   success(function (data) {
    $scope.items = data;
   });
});

ToDoApp.controller("ListQuestionByTagsCtrl", function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
   var Tag1 = $routeParams.tag1, Tag2 = $routeParams.tag2, Tag3 = $routeParams.tag3;
   $http.get('http://LocalHost:8080/FetchQuestions/service/question/'+Tag1+','+Tag2+','+Tag3).
   success(function (data) {
      $scope.items = data;
   });
});

ToDoApp.controller("InsertQuestionAnswerCtrl",function($scope, $routeParams, $http){
   var userid = $routeParam.user_id,  qtnid = $routeParams.qtn_id, ans = $routeParam.answer;
     $http.get('http://LocalHost:8080/FetchQuestions/service/question/insert/'+userid+'/'+qtnid+'/'+ans).
   success(function (data){
      $scope.items = data;
   });
});
```

The Controller Invokes a **RESTful** Webservice (***FetchQuestions***) That returns Data in **JSON** Format.

The **ListQuestion.html** simply uses `ng-repeat` on scope variable *items* and displays data in tabular format as follows :

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>{{item.Question_id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Question_Text}}</td>            
</tr>
```

When I am deploying the Project (FetchQuestionAngularJS) on WAMP server, I am getting the following error message :

> -Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route 
>    <- ngViewDirective

**What Am I doing Wrong ?**

How can I Make my AngularJS Project (**FetchQuestionsAngularJS**) communicate with Spring RESTful WebService Project (**FetchQuestions**) ?

The Structure for my FetchQuestions Porject is Given Below :

[image]

I have checked several tutorials and blogs online and am stuck So Any Help is Welcome.

**After Certain Edit On app.js**

```
var urlBase="http://LocalHost:8080/FetchQuestions/";
var ToDoApp = angular.module("ToDoApp", ['ngRoute','ngResource']).
config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
                    when('/service/question/', 
                    { controller: 'ListQuestionCtrl', 
                      templateUrl:'ListQuestions.html'
                 }).when('/service/question/:tag1,:tag2,:tag3',
                    { controller: 'ListQuestionByTagsCtrl',
                      templateUrl:'ListQuestions.html'
                 }).when('/service/question/insert/:user_id/:qtn_id/:answer',
                    { controller: 'InsertQuestionAnswerCtrl',
                      templateUrl:'InsertAnswer.html'
                 }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

ToDoApp.factory('TodoService',[ '$resource',function($resource) {
return new Questions($resource);
}]);

function Questions(resource){

this.resource = resource;
this.getAllQuestions = function(scope){
     resource('http://LocalHost:8080/FetchQuestions/service/question/').
     success(function (data){
         scope.items = data;
     });
};
this.getQuestion = function(scope,Tag1,Tag2,Tag3){
    resource('http://LocalHost:8080/FetchQuestions/service/question/'+Tag1+','+Tag2+','+Tag3).
    success(function (data){
        scope.items = data;
    });
};
this.insertQuestion = function(scope,userid,qtnid,ans){
    resource('http://LocalHost:8080/FetchQuestions/service/question/insert/'+userid+'/'+qtnid+'/'+ans).
    success(function (data){
        $scope.items = data;
    });
};  
}


ToDoApp.controller("ListQuestionCtrl",['$scope','TodoService', function ($scope, TodoService) {
TodoService.getAllQuestions($scope);
}]);

ToDoApp.controller("ListQuestionByTagsCtrl",['$scope','TodoService', function ($scope, $routeParams, TodoService) {
var Tag1 = $routeParams.tag1, Tag2 = $routeParams.tag2, Tag3 = $routeParams.tag3;
TodoService.getQuestions($scope,Tag1,Tag2,Tag3);    
}]);

ToDoApp.controller("InsertQuestionAnswerCtrl",['$scope','TodoService',function($scope, $routeParams, TodoService){
var userid = $routeParam.user_id,  qtnid = $routeParams.qtn_id, ans = $routeParam.answer;
TodoService.insertQuestion($scope,userid,qtnid,ans);    
}]);
```

To my Disappointment the The Previous ERROR still keeps repeating.
I am completely struck. Any Help on This Question will be appreciated greatly.

The Error message Thrown by The Console is as Follows :

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective

Answer (score 0):

Try putting quotes around the controller name in your routeprovider.

```
config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
                when('/service/question/', 
                { controller: 'ListQuestionCtrl', 
                  templateUrl: urlBase+'ListQuestions.html'
             }).when('/service/question/:tag1,:tag2,:tag3',
                { controller: 'ListQuestionByTagsCtrl',
                  templateUrl: urlBase+'ListQuestions.html'
             }).when('/service/question/insert/:user_id/:qtn_id/:answer',
                { controller: 'InsertQuestionAnswerCtrl',
                  templateUrl: urlBase+'InsertAnswer.html'
             }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

Comment: Does Solve The Previous Error Message buts Genarates a new One ---Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective